# Can we set Alerts on the site level? so any modification to the site's lists will send an email

Tags: 2013, list, alert, configuration, site-settings

We have a sharepoint server 2013 on-premises. and i know that users can set alerts on the lists and list's items(from Alert Me). but can we set alert on the site level, so any modification to the site's lists and items will send a notification email ? is this possible ?

Comment: please refer this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/635b971a-48d9-4d06-be0c-770ee614b46a/alerts-at-site-level-team-site-template?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: @adilahmed so from the link u provide seems there is not a way to set alerts on the site level..

Comment: Not OOB, though a custom solution to iterate over all lists and add alerts would be doable. Don't go DB diving though - that way leads to unsupportability.